# add value to checkboxes similar to radio buttons asp.net mvc razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have in my view this form:

```
@foreach (var partner in ((List<string>)ViewBag.Email))
            {
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label> @Html.CheckBox("partners", true, new { @class = "myCheckbox" }) @ViewBag.FirstName[item] @ViewBag.Lastname[item] ( @partner.ToString() )  
                    </label>
                </div>
                item += 1;
            }
```

These checkboxes are displayed dynamically(foreach). All the checkboxes have the same name "partners" and all are checked by default. How then I can check, which checkboxes are checked?

My controller method where I work with this data from form:

```
 public ActionResult Create(List<string> partners){
   ...
 }
```

How to change my form in view, that I would know identified different checkboxes?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You  can add value like this: `@Html.CheckBox("partners", true, new { @class = "myCheckbox", value = "YourValue"  })`

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use list of Patner objects instead of list of strings, which will have some ID, Partner and Selected property. And then use this:

```
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Selected)...
```

Your view will set property Selected to true for all checked checkbox items.

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.CheckBox` will create an additional hidden field you can use plain `html` in that case like following. Only checked checkbox value will be posted.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked name="partners" class="myCheckbox" value="YourValueHere"/>
```

Hope this will help you.